# Transform data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have data frame:

```
x1  x2  value_x1    value_x2
a   b   1           2       
a   c   3           4
b   c   5           6
```

Can I get the following data frame?

```
a   b   c
1   2   0
3   0   4
0   5   6
```

I tried pivot_table and melt, but result is not suitable.

Thank you.

Comment: Use *pivot_table* function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['x', 'value_x'], i='index', j='a')

print (df)
         x  value_x
index a            
0     1  a        1
1     1  a        3
2     1  b        5
0     2  b        2
1     2  c        4
2     2  c        6
```

And then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with some data cleaning:

```
df = (df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .set_index('x', append=True)['value_x']
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .rename_axis(None)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  0
1  3  0  4
2  0  5  6
```